# Как создать задержку в коде

Tags: c++

Я написал змейку, но она движется очень быстро. Для фикса надо только добавить в конце цикла `while` задержку, например, в пол секунды, как это сделать?

Comment: Ответы ниже решают Вашу проблему, но делают это плохо. Вам нужно использовать таймер и менять позицию по таймеру, использование `sleep` это почти всегда неправильно.

Comment: Скорее всего в данном случае sleep будет самым хороших решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть несколько вариантов для решения этой задачи:

#### 1 вариант:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(500000000));
```

#### 2 вариант:

```
#include <unistd.h> // для Unix систем
...
sleep(500);
```

#### 3 вариант:

```
#include <windows.h> // для Win32 систем
...
Sleep(500);
```

#### 4 вариант:

```
#include <dos.h> // для Win32 систем
...
delay(500);
```

Но конечно же, данные варианты не являются наилучшим способом для решения этой задачи. В частности я бы сделал для змейки таймер(тактовый генератор), которые на каждый такт изменял бы позицию змейки на поле, а также генерировал новую еду для змейки к примеру и многое другое... Подробнее об этом вы можете прочитать [здесь](https://habr.com/post/83040/).

Answer (score 2):

sleep в помощь. Но в зависимости от оси/компилятора могут быть разные решения, но с новым стандартом можно использовать [sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Задержка в пол секунды будет выглядеть так

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
```

Answer (score 1):

В цикле движения используй Sleep(кол_во миллисекунд)

(Ниже код для примера, который можешь у себя прогнать, чтобы увидеть, как все работает)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
short a = 0;
int main() {
    while(a < 10) {
    a++;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    }
}
```

Comment: В С++ нет функции `Sleep`

Comment: Пользуюсь компилятором Dev C++ 5.11, все прекрасно работает

Comment: Это не отменяет того факт, что в C++ такой функции **нет**.

Comment: @Cormentor: Это функция из winapi от майкрософт, ТС не указывал под что пишет.

Answer (score 0):

ну есть `#include<windows.h>`

а там есть функция `sleep(кол-во миллисекунд)` она останавливает программу на столько-то миллисекунд(1000 миллисекунд = 1 секунда)